# fill with None to specific position in accordance with another list

Tags: python

I have this kind of dataset:

```
thelist = [[
    [['AA', '24', '', None]],
           
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['48079687', 'Pers', '5', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro'], ['1', 'YES', 'Animal', 'Ksiriki']],
    
    [['AA', '26', '', None]],
    
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['56779687', 'Pers', '1', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro'], ['1', 'NO', 'Cotton', 'Fid']],
    
    [['AA', '27', '', None]],
    
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['34579687', 'Pers', '1', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro']],
    
    [['AA', '29', '', 'Someth']],
    
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['12079687', 'Pers', '5', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro'], ['1', 'NO', 'BAMB', 'ST']]]]
```

and I am trying to extract some fields:

```
first = []
second = []
aa = []
for idx, element in enumerate(thelist):
    for idx2, item in enumerate(element):
        if item[0][0] == 'AA' and item[0][1].isdigit():
                aa.append(item[0][1])
                   
        if len(item) >= 2 and len(item[1]) > 3:
            if item[0][0] == 'AA':
                if (item[1][2] is not None) and (not item[1][2].isdigit()):
                        first.append(item[1][2])
                        second.append(item[1][3])
```

Right now, I have:

```
aa
['24', '26', '27', '29']

first
['Animal', 'Cotton', 'BAMB']

second
['Ksiriki', 'Fid', 'ST']
```

As you can see, even though I have the `AA` 27, it does not contain any other element like the other data. I want in this position, where no other element is found, to fill  the `first` and `second` lists with `None`.

So, I want to preserve the order and I want to have:

```
aa
    ['24', '26', '27', '29']

    first
    ['Animal', 'Cotton', None, 'BAMB']

    second
    ['Ksiriki', 'Fid', None, 'ST']
```

Comment: If you want something appended if and only if a number is appended to "aa", then nest the second if block, that starts with `if len(item) >= 2`, under the first if block, then use an else block to append `None`.

Comment: @Joe:It doesn't work. I am not sure if I miss something.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento:No, it is right. I am extracting those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your data is organized by triples and when you do the second `if` you do not know if you are in the proper part of the current triple. You are trying to get this by entry format. But data may be missed. You want to add `None` in this case. At this point, it becomes complicated to decide whether the data is missing or the entry is not proper. That’s why you cannot simply add else section.

The logic looks overcomplicated for this simple input. I would suggest filtering data by natural triples.

```
first = []
second = []
aa = []
for element in thelist:
    for idx in range(0, len(element), 3):
        first_entry = element[idx]
        third_entry = element[idx + 2]
        if first_entry[0][0] != 'AA':  # yet there is no data to filter with this if
            continue
        aa.append(first_entry[0][1])

        if len(third_entry) >= 2 and len(third_entry[1]) > 3:
            first.append(third_entry[1][2])
            second.append(third_entry[1][3])
        else:
            first.append(None)
            second.append(None)
```

Or, if my assumption about triples is not correct, use may reserve Nones and fill later  if proper entry is found:

```
first = []
second = []
aa = []
for element in thelist:
    for item in element:
        if item[0][0] == 'AA' and item[0][1].isdigit():
            aa.append(item[0][1])
            first.append(None)
            second.append(None)

        if len(item) >= 2 and len(item[1]) > 3:
            if item[0][0] == 'AA':
                if (item[1][2] is not None) and (not item[1][2].isdigit()):
                    first[-1] = item[1][2]
                    second[-1] = item[1][3]
```

Comment: This works for this dataset. But the problem is that I can't use `range(0, len(element), 3)` step `3` in my real case. This won't be the case.

Comment: George, you should provide dataset that reflects your real case. Anyway, I amended the answer with the reservation variant. Maybe it suits your real case.

Comment: Nice one! Seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data shown, it appears that the string "Syg." is the key to this solution as follows:

```
thelist = [
    [
        [["AA", "24", "", None]],
        [["AA", "Title", "A/A agr"], ["48079687", "Pers", "5", ""]],
        [["AA", "Syg.", "Cro"], ["1", "YES", "Animal", "Ksiriki"]],
        [["AA", "26", "", None]],
        [["AA", "Title", "A/A agr"], ["56779687", "Pers", "1", ""]],
        [["AA", "Syg.", "Cro"], ["1", "NO", "Cotton", "Fid"]],
        [["AA", "27", "", None]],
        [["AA", "Title", "A/A agr"], ["34579687", "Pers", "1", ""]],
        [["AA", "Syg.", "Cro"]],
        [["AA", "29", "", "Someth"]],
        [["AA", "Title", "A/A agr"], ["12079687", "Pers", "5", ""]],
        [["AA", "Syg.", "Cro"], ["1", "NO", "BAMB", "ST"]],
    ]
]

aa = []
first = []
second = []

for a in thelist:
    for b in a:
        key, x, *_ = b[0]
        if key == "AA":
            if x.isdigit():
                aa.append(x)
            elif x == "Syg.":
                if len(b) > 1 and len(b[1]) > 3:
                    first.append(b[1][2])
                    second.append(b[1][3])
                else:
                    first.append(None)
                    second.append(None)

print(aa)
print(first)
print(second)
```

**Output:**

```
['24', '26', '27', '29']
['Animal', 'Cotton', None, 'BAMB']
['Ksiriki', 'Fid', None, 'ST']
```