# match specific list name values with another name value

Tags: python

This is a continuation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77445115/fill-with-none-to-specific-position-in-accordance-with-another-list/77445618?noredirect=1#77446272).

Now, I have this dataset with the addition of `CODE`.

```
thelist = [[
    [['AA', '24', '', None]],
           
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['48079687', 'Pers', '5', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro'], ['1', 'YES', 'Animal', 'Ksiriki']],
    
    [['CODE'], ['NB-1', 's'], ['NB-17', '']],
    
    [['AA', '26', '', None]],
    
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['56779687', 'Pers', '1', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro'], ['1', 'NO', 'Cotton', 'Fid']],
    
    [['CODE'], ['NB-11', 'g']],
    
    [['AA', '27', '', None]],
    
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['34579687', 'Pers', '1', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro']],
    
    [['AA', '29', '', 'Someth']],
    
    [['AA', 'Title', 'A/A agr'], ['12079687', 'Pers', '5', '']],
    
    [['AA', 'Syg.', 'Cro'], ['1', 'NO', 'BAMB', 'ST']]]]
```

I want to be able to match the corresponding `AA` to the `CODE` if any.

Right now:

```
first = []
second = []
aa = []
codes = []
for element in thelist:
    for item in element:
        if item[0][0] == 'AA' and item[0][1].isdigit():
            aa.append(item[0][1])
            first.append(None)
            second.append(None)

        if len(item) >= 2 and len(item[1]) > 3:
            if item[0][0] == 'AA':
                if (item[1][2] is not None) and (not item[1][2].isdigit()):
                    first[-1] = item[1][2]
                    second[-1] = item[1][3]  
       
        if item[0][0] == 'CODE':
            for i in range(1, 100):
                try:
                    codes.append(item[i][0])
                except:
                    pass  
                
print(aa)
print(first)
print(second)
print(codes)
```

the results are:

```
['24', '26', '27', '29']
['Animal', 'Cotton', None, 'BAMB']
['Ksiriki', 'Fid', None, 'ST']
['NB-1', 'NB-17', 'NB-11']
```

I want to have something like:

```
['24', '26', '27', '29']
['Animal', 'Cotton', None, 'BAMB']
['Ksiriki', 'Fid', None, 'ST']
[['NB-1', 'NB-17'], 'NB-11', None, None]
```

So , I want to group the number of `CODES` (NB-1, NB-17 etc..) to the specific `AA`.

The solution with `codes[-1] = item[i][0]` as in previous question doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your logic for appending 'CODE', `for i in range(1, 100):` this in particular seems unnecessary, instead you can just use list comprehension for the same:

```
sub_codes = [x[0] for x in item[1:]] # list comp
sub_codes = str(sub_codes[0]) if len(sub_codes) == 1 else sub_codes # append as str if only one code
codes.append(sub_codes)
```

And in case you don't find any "CODE" for each "aa" you need to append `None`. This might change based on the structure of your data, but based on your minimal example the below code should work. See the code in full:

```
first = []
second = []
aa = []
codes = []
for ii,element in enumerate(thelist):
    for jj,item in enumerate(element):
        if len(aa) > len(codes) + 1:
            codes.append(None)
        if item[0][0] == 'AA' and item[0][1].isdigit():
            aa.append(item[0][1])
            first.append(None)
            second.append(None)

        if len(item) >= 2 and len(item[1]) > 3:
            if item[0][0] == 'AA':
                if (item[1][2] is not None) and (not item[1][2].isdigit()):
                    first[-1] = item[1][2]
                    second[-1] = item[1][3]  
        
        if item[0][0] == 'CODE':
            sub_codes = [x[0] for x in item[1:]]
            sub_codes = str(sub_codes[0]) if len(sub_codes) == 1 else sub_codes
            codes.append(sub_codes)

if len(aa) > len(codes):
    codes.append(None)        
    
        
print(aa)
print(first)
print(second)
print(codes)
```

Output:

```
['24', '26', '27', '29']
['Animal', 'Cotton', None, 'BAMB']
['Ksiriki', 'Fid', None, 'ST']
[['NB-1', 'NB-17'], 'NB-11', None, None]
```